# Capturing mouse click co-ordinates on canvas using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, canvas

I'm newbie to angularjs and canvas. What I'm trying to do is draw a circle at a point on the screen where the user clicks first. For every subsequent click, capture the co-ordinates, draw another circle at the point of the second click, and connect the two with a bezier curve. If the y co-ordinate of the second click is higher/lower than the first, the two circles have to be connected by a s-type bezier curve. If the two have the same y co-ordinates they need to be connected with a straight line. All subsequent circles are connected to the first one.

I can't seem to get started even with the first part. Here's my code.

```
<canvas  ng-click="addOnClick($event)" id="canvas1" width="600" height= "600"></canvas>
```

Here's the code to capture the click

```
$scope.doClick = function(event){

    var x = event.x;
    var y = event.y;
    var offsetX = event.offsetX;
    var offsetY = event.offsetY;

    alert(x, y, offsetX, offsetY);
};
```

But nothing seems to happen when I click on my canvas. Can someone help me get started.

Comment: have you tried: ng-click="doClick($event)"?

Comment: I'm kind of a little lost on how angular finds the click. This is my plnk
http://plnkr.co/edit/rYVLgB14IutNh1F4MN6T?p=preview

Comment: please check answer below, and tell me if it answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a [fork of your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gyi2WG?p=preview) which prints what you wanted to capture in the console (you could also alert it if you really are fond of alerts, but I recommend using the console instead)(*)

---

I defined a module named plunker:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {...});
```

Then in the controller:

```
var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
```

and your html:

```
ng-click="doClick($event)"
```

---

Your plunk was not working, as you had not declared a module.

I suggest you read this: [The Basics](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) which explains how to build a minimum setup.

---

(*) alerts will give you trouble if you accidentally run into an endless loop; also, you can print many more things in the console.

Comment: Thanks @Manube that worked. Could you help me a little with the next step. Drawing a circle at the first location and then one a second relative to the first and connecting them using a bezier curve. I think from there I can manage the rest. Understand its a tall ask, but really appreciate the help.

Comment: I am afraid I am much more familiar with angularjs than with svg. I suggest you post a new question, and the svg gurus will be happy to help. You could post the link to the fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/gyi2WG?p=preview so people have something to work on